# Delete particular objects from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a object of array stored in local-storage as shown below

```
  var todos = [
    {"id":0,"text":"Make lunch","completed":true},
    {"id":1,"text":"Do laundry","completed":false},
    {"id":2,"text":"Complete Project","completed":true}
  ]
```

How can i delete all objects that are completed?
Please tell me how to delete it with splice method as i cant replace array i want to just remove it from array!(as my project requirements)
Thanks for any help

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I tried todos.splice(todos.findIndex((todo) => todo.completed), 1); but it wont worked.

Comment: @Darshit  use this Underscore library filter function   https://underscorejs.org/#filter

Comment: Please tell me how to delete it with splice method as i cant replace array i want to just remove it from array!

Comment: That is unfair - you asked a question, which @Fawzi answered correctly, and you accepted.  Then you ***changed*** the question, and unselected Fawzi's answer.  That is disrespectful of people's efforts that they've put into helping you, and it will make people far less inclined to help you now or in the future.

Comment: I appreciate @fawzi for its efforts
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the javascript  [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
todos=todos.filter(todo=>!todo.completed);
```

Comment: never used angular before, but check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-change-detection-manually-in-angular) out as you might be calling the updated outside Angular zone.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter uncompleted todos like:

```
const unCompletedTodos = todos.filter(todo => !todo.completed);
```

Also you don't have to use `const` you can use `var` but I recommend you to use `const` or `let` instead of `var`

Answer (score 0):

```
var todos = [
{"id":0,"text":"Make lunch","completed":true},
{"id":1,"text":"Do laundry","completed":false},
{"id":2,"text":"Complete Project","completed":true} ];

var inCompletes = todos.filter(item => !item.completed );
```

**inCompletes** will return an array of objects with completed is false.

**Output**

```
inCompletes = [{"id":1,"text":"Do laundry","completed":false}];
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this would do the job

```
var filteredAry = todos.filter(function(e) { return e.competed !== 'true' })
```

Comment: This won't work because, firstly, `"completed"` is misspelled.  But, secondly, you've put quotes around `true`.